# Prove that $a^m+b^m=c^m$ and $a^n+b^n=c^n$ imply that $m=n$

Tags: calculus, real-numbers

The question is as follows:

> Prove that $a^m+b^m=c^m$ and $a^n+b^n=c^n$ imply that $m=n$ where $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R^+}$.

I tried using binomial expansion, but it didn't work. It'd be great if someone could give me a hint.

Comment: This is false as stated. Consider $a=b=c=0$. Or $a=-b, c=0$ with $m,n$ odd integers.

Comment: @dxiv Is it now correct?

Comment: Hint: try to prove that $(a/c)^n+(b/c)^n$ is injective as a function of $n$.

Comment: Was this a problem from a contest math book?

Comment: @Alephnull Yes.

Comment: m,n are odd, a=-b.

Comment: @ArianaGrande But, $c$ has to be non-zero.

Comment: @dxiv this is trivial (by calculus) if each summand is increasing or each summand is decreasing. I guess I would like to ask if the sum of exponential functions must be an exponential function (1-1) or if I have to go deeper into the differential calculus.

Comment: @dxiv I think the sum works out to be 1-1 increasing because a growing exponential function is increasingly increasing whereas a decaying exponential is only decreasingly decreasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following dxiv's comment, we can try to prove the equivalent problem that $$\left(\frac{a}{c}\right)^n+\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)^n=1$$
has at most $1$ solution in $n$ for any given $a$, $b$, and $c$. Since we have assumed that all numbers are not $0$, this division is legal. To simplify notation a bit, let $u=a/c$ and $v=b/c$.

I first claim that $u$ and $v$ must both be less than $1$ to have any solution. Indeed, if $u\geq1$ or $v \geq 1$, we have that $u^n\geq1$ or $v^n\geq 1$. In all cases, $u^n+v^n>1$ for all $n$ giving no solutions.

Now $u,v<1$ and so both $u^n$ and $v^n$ are strictly decreasing. Thus $u^n+v^n$ is strictly decreasing. From this, $u^n+v^n$ is injective in $n$ and the desired result immediately follows.

Answer (score 0):

As dxiv said consider (a/c)^n + (b/c)^n but instead permit n arbitrary real number greater than or equal to 1. We wish to show the sum is 1-1. If both summands are increasing or decreasing the sum is increasing or decreasing and thus is 1-1. THe case where one summand is constant is similarly trivial. Thus WLOG a/c is less than 1 but b/c is greater than 1. Then (a/c)^n is less than 1 and so is the absolute value of its derivative. (b/c)^n is greater than 1 and so is the absolute value of its derivative. Thus the derivative of the sum is positive and we have a 1-1 function. Thus it only assumes 1 once (a rephrasing of our theorem).

Comment: $\left({a \over c}\right)^n<1$ doesn't necessarily imply that the derivative is less than $1$.

Comment: @SayantanSantra even with n>1 (the domain of interest)?

Comment: Yeah. Even then.